# Struct trait error: Wrong number of type arguments: Expected 1, found 0

Tags: rust

I'm kinda new to the concept of how Rust works even after experimenting with it for a couple months. I'm writing a webserver with R2D2 (0.8.0) and Rocket (0.4.4) + Rocket_cors (0.5.2)

Rocket allows you to feed it structs into a state pool, so I don't have to initialize my Postgres server every time somebody sends a request. Here's the code:

```
struct ConnectionPool<M: r2d2::ManageConnection> {
    val: r2d2::Pool<M>
}

#[post("/upload", format = "application/json", data = "<data>")]
fn upload(data: Data, state: rocket::State<ConnectionPool>) {
    if data.peek_complete() {
        println!("All of the data: {:?}", str::from_utf8(data.peek()).unwrap());
    }
    //data.stream_to_file(env::temp_dir().join("upload.txt"))
    //    .map(|n| n.to_string())
    //    .map_err(Debug)
}
```

Obviously, this is just a snippet of the code, but r2d2::ConnectionPool requires one type identifier: giving me this error if I ignore the requirement (on line 4 in the code snippet above):

```
wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0

expected 1 type argumentrustc(E0107)
main.rs(45, 44): expected 1 type argument
```

But when I try my best-ish to solve the problem by updating the code:

```
fn upload(data: Data, state: rocket::State<ConnectionPool>) {

    |
    v

fn upload(data: Data, state: rocket::State<ConnectionPool<r2d2::ManageConnection>>) {
```

I get this error:

```
the size for values of type `(dyn r2d2::ManageConnection + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time

doesn't have a size known at compile-time

help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn r2d2::ManageConnection + 'static)`
```

Comment: `r2d2::ManageConnection` is a trait. You need to specifiy the actual, concrete connection type you are using. You didn't share the code creating the connection pool, so we can't tell you what that type is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r2d2::ManageConnection` is a trait. Rather than repeating the trait name you need to pass it a concrete type that implements the trait. Since you're using Postgres you probably want:

```
fn upload(data: Data, state: rocket::State<ConnectionPool<PostgresConnectionManager>>)
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your code database agnostic you can make the method generic over the connection type and let the caller decide:

```
fn upload<M: r2d2::ManageConnection>(data: Data, state: rocket::State<ConnectionPool<M>>)
```